# contenteditable margin is applied to other absolute-positioned elements

Tags: html, google-chrome, css

I have a contenteditable div and am placing another absolute-positioned element (a small box) on top of it.

Weird thing: in Chrome, the `padding-right` property keeps being applied to the small box, even though it's not in the CSS. Furthermore, the padding isn't applied to the contenteditable.

- **http://jsfiddle.net/xBU7D/**

Is this a Chrome bug? I'm opretty sure I'm doing it right:

```
<div contenteditable=true>hello</div>
<div id=closer></div>
```

and

```
   div[contenteditable] {
        border:1px solid #900;
        width:200px;  
        overflow:hidden;
        white-space:nowrap;
        padding-right:20px; /* <- the wascawwy wabbit */
    }
    #closer {
        position:absolute;
        border:1px solid #090;
        width:20px;
        height:20px;
        top:0px;
        left:180px;
    }
    body {padding:0;margin:0;}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `padding-right` is actually not being applied to the small box it just looks like it.

The `padding-right` adds to the width of your contenteditable div making it `220px` wide.

Your small div is positioned absolute with a width of `20px` and left of `180px` which leads to a `20px` gap on the right - but that's not the `padding-right`. You just have to change the `left: 180px` to `left: 200px` on your small box or change the `width: 180px` to `width: 160px` of your contenteditable div.

http://jsfiddle.net/xBU7D/2/

Answer (score 1):

The `padding-right:20px` you have there actually makes your 200px contenteditable div 220px.
So, if you set your second div 200px to the left instead of 180px it lines up perfectly.

[**http://jsfiddle.net/xBU7D/3/**](http://jsfiddle.net/xBU7D/3/)

Comment: it's a q&a site not a c&p site

Comment: Hope you realise that while you type your answer there is at least one more person doing the same. Stop acting silly, your answer was not that brilliant for somebody to copy it :)

Answer (score 1):

Accepting Horen's answer as a thank you for providing an explanation that made me realize what's happening.

The *real* reason my code didn't do what I thought it's supposed to do, is the darn box model change. I'm with [quirksmode.org on that one](http://quirksmode.org/css/user-interface/boxsizing.html), the W3C box model of `content-box` is counter-intuitive to me. `padding` is supposed to be inside of the content.

http://jsfiddle.net/xBU7D/4/   uses `border-box` and all is well.